Java application not going through the debug breakpoints on IntelliJ idea
I am working on a SAP Commerce project. After I start the application server on my local in debug mode and run the debugger from my IDE i.e. IntelliJ. The debugger skips all the breakpoints and shows me the response after I hit an API from my API platform.
I have already verified that when I hit a particular API then it must go through the given breakpoints.
Few of the observations that I took are as follows.
When hit for the first time the application does halts at the breakpoint, but subsequent retries fails.
When I change the params of the Api and hit again the application halts at breakpoints when in the earlier attempts it was failing. But this too halts for the first time
This issue started appearing after I changed my API client from Postman to Insomnia due to my employer's compliance issue, I suspect caching on insomnia but idk.
I am expecting the application to halt at the breakpoint every time I hit the API from the Insomnia.
I even don't have idea what to search on the web to fix this issue.

Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the steps to reproduce the problem. A sample project would help a lot. Make sure you run the latest IntelliJ IDEA version.

Maybe you have a caching controller and methods. Maybe Postman makes calls without previous cookies and the new tool does.

@CrazyCoder The only reason I didn't log a bug at jet brain was because of my lack of a sample project. and making a sample project on sap-commerce is both time consuming and storage consuming. But I have the latest update of the Idea on my local.

@mkysoft Thanks for your comment. could you kindly elaborate that since I am new to development?
also I did find a similar question on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713336/intellij-debugger-not-stopping-at-breakpoints-after-local-server-endpoint-is-alr?rq=2

Your issue looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75816643/debug-point-not-hitting-in-the-restcontroller-in-spring-boot-test and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-311166/Breakpoint-not-hit-again-after-Step-Over-in-a-Spring-Boot-app. Please follow YouTrack for updates if you think it's the same problem.
